# Deploying Spring boot war to Tomcat 8

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat

I want to deploy my Spring boot application (.war) to an external Tomcat-Server. My application works fine in Eclipse with my local Tomcat 8 and jdk 8. Furthermore, we are using maven and

Now we had to setup a whole server from scratch and we tried to do our best, but the application won't find any Services. We just can call static html, css and js files. As far as we want to call a service we get an 404 error.

**Can anyone show me a step-by-step setting up tomcat with deploying the war?**

Here is my startclass:

```
@PropertySources({
        @PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties"),
        @PropertySource("classpath:/messages_de.properties")
})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
}
```

Here is the pom.xml...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.quanto</groupId>
    <artifactId>QuantoSpringMVC</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>QuantoSpringMVC Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for JPA, use hibernate-entitymanager instead of hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1-RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for generating hibernate-model classes >>> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.equinox</groupId>
            <artifactId>app</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.200-v20130910-1609</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <<< -->
        <!-- SPRING DEPENDENCIES/REPO/PLUGINS STARTS HERE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SECURITY START -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SECURITY ENDS -->
        <!-- Authentification (Access Directory...) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper-spring</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <tomcat.version>8.0.32</tomcat.version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>QuantoSpringMVC</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your manager url with text its new change

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>{version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://yourRemoteServer:8888/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/{project.artifactId}</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Now you can run mvn tomcat7:deploy( or redeploy)

**PS** : i know that the command tomcat7:deploy (redeploy) exists but i'm not sure for tomcat8:deploy  !

Comment: Could it be that my url ends on **manager/html**?
What do I still need to customize in this plugin?

I am using "maven install" from eclipse and then deploy the .war with the help of the tomcat manager gui. Could that work?

Comment: this method is considered with using the plugin tomcat. And for the plugin the extension `\text` is the update concerning deploying with tomcat 6 and tomcat 7 . Unfortunately i know this solution but if you try to deploy directly with your manager gui i'm not sure that will work.

Comment: It's working now. We installed the right java 8 version. Then setting this code above in pom.xml, using "maven install" and uploading over the gui.

Comment: And important to say: you cannot override .war files. You need to undeploy explicit and then deploy the new one...

That was my biggest mistake when trying to deploy over the gui.

Comment: I knew it already ! Personnaly i prefer deploying manually under `~\webapp` of tomcat ! and when i wanna to redeploy, i delete the ancient version Under `~\webapp` and Under `~\work\Catalina\localhost` and past the new version